# if-else condition - how to "get back" to outer branch?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, syntax

I have the following code:

```
if (condition1)
{
   if (condition2)
   {
      Do sth.
   }
   else if (condition3)
   {
      Do sth.
   }
   else
   {
      // get back to check condition4.
   }
}
else if (condition4)
{
   Do sth.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (condition1 && (condition2 || condition3))
{
    if (condition2)
    {
        Do sth.
    }
    else if (condition3)
    {
        Do sth.
    }
}
else if (condition4)
{
   Do sth.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rickard. I added some code I forgot. Do you have an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL someCondition;
if (condition1)
{
   if (condition2)
   {
      //Do sth.
   }
   else if (condition3)
   {
      //Do sth.
   }
   else
   {
      // get back to check condition4.
      someCondition = YES;
   }
}
if (condition4 && someCondition)
{
   //Do sth.
}
```

Comment: Yech. While a flag isn't terrible, the loop is. Can this answer be rewritten *without* the use of a loop? (Also note the question was updated with a 3rd nested branch.)

Comment: @pst maybe there is some unclarity in the question. OP says "go back" and then "to check condition 4". If we are going back then we probably need a loop. If we're just checking condition 4, then you're right we don't need a loop.

Comment: "Try condition 4 even if condition 1 is true but neither condition 2 or condition 3 are."